# Asp.net Webservice response fetch in React native

Tags: asp.net, react-native, web-services

we are trying to fetch webservices json response in our react native. We are enable to fetch after trying it in different ways. our Json response from webservices is like this{

**"Table":[ 
      { 
         "code":"M251",
         "firstname":"MINAL JAGDISH TRIVEDI"
      }
   ]
}**

The code we are writting to in react native to fetch this response is

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
     return fetch('URL',{ 
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
   })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.Table,

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }



  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}

          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.code}, {item.firstname}</Text>}

          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
      </View>
    );

  }
}
```

Please provide solution if someone as already faced this problem.

Comment: Can you provide more details may be postman example that  worked for you?
Put console.logs  you didn't described where is  the problem in fetch or in render, how do you know

Comment: I used alert to print my Datasource in which i am storing my responseJSON. It give me error as "Undefined"